# How to import existing android studio project in the android studio?

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I import the project or open the existing project I get:

[image: Screenshot of the android studio]

So the issue is:

> gradle: download https://services.gradle.org/distibutions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip"

Which can be seen at the bottom of the image and then nothing happens. So for resolving this after searching in google and stack overflow I downloaded the gradle from [this](https://gradle.org/downloads) and add in the "Path" system variable and it is installed properly as checked from cmd by

> gradle -v

as I am using windows. After that :
[image: Gradle setting in Android Studio]

But the problem still exists, is there anything I am missing? I am new to Android Studio and gradle.

Comment: go to settings > gradle and set the path to your gradle directory which have bin folder inside.

Comment: @pyus13: Do i have to this for each project or by closing all project and then configure --> setting --> gradle If second is the case then i have edited my post you can see that the gradle was added before I posted this question.